# Is it true that $(p,q)=(q',p')$?

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b,p,q,p',q'\in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $a(p^2+q^2)+bp'q'=a(p'^2+q'^2)+bpq$, is it true that $(p,q)=(q',p')$?

EDIT: This is wrong, I have made a new topic here: [Which linear transformations preserve this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187519/which-linear-transformations-preserve-this)

Comment: We could also have $(p, q) = (p', q')$, or $(p, q) = (-p', -q')$...

Comment: Is $(p,q)=(q',p')$ an equation between ordered pairs, or between greatest common divisors?

Comment: Does "integers" imply for you that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero? Or perhaps even positive?

Comment: When $a = b = 0$, all other variables are irrelevant, so the other variables could be totally unrelated.

Comment: @Ark: By now you should probably ask an entirely new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

The equation you want to solve is equivalent to
$$ a(p^2+q^2-p^2-q'^2) = b(pq-p'q') $$
Unless I'm missing something, you can choose $p,q,p',q'$ essentially *arbitrarily* and then set
$$ a=pq-p'q' \qquad b=p^2+q^2-p'^2-q'^2 $$

Comment: @Ark: Still, this procedure gives you a way to construct an $a$ and $b$ for which your equalities are _not_ necessarily satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

No. Choose $a=2,b=3,p=2=q,p'=2,q'=1$. Then $(p,q)\neq(p',q')$ (no matter if you consider ordered pairs or gcd), but the left hand side of your equation is $a(p^2+q^2)+bp'q'=2\cdot(4+4)+3\cdot2\cdot1=16+6=22$ and the right hand side equals $2(4+1)+3\cdot2\cdot2=10+12=22$, too.